# Protractor click svg element breaks on latest firefox(v.34)

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am testing with the latest version of Protractor on different browsers. In this test spec, i want to right click on a svg element to trigger a specific event on a given point within the svg. To click on this element, I'm using this function

```
function rightClick(svgElement) {
  scrollToElement(svgElement).then(function () {   
            browser.actions()
                .mouseMove(svgElement)
                .click(protractor.Button.RIGHT)
                .perform();
  });
}
```

I running the test on different selenium hubs with different browsers. The test passes for all browsers (chrome, firefox27, ie11+10) except for firefox34. When I watch the test, I can recognize that the mouse hovers the svg element(because the element is highlighted), but after the right click, it opens the firefox context menu instead of calling the eventlistener.

Another important point is, that the test fails irregular.

I tried different workarounds like performing the right click with two different *browser.actions()* (the first one to move on the element, and the second one to perform a right click).

I also tried to click through the element coordinates... but nothing worked

To prevent errors caused by resolutions, I maximize the windows and scroll to the element with an offset of 75px to prevent browser pop ups of breaking the tests.

Comment: You probably need to call evt.preventDefault() in the handlers where evt is an event object.

Comment: evt.preventDefault() is already used