# Protractor mouse action does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, protractor

firefox version: 34.0.5

Recently I am using the mouseaction function of protractor. All worked fine on chrome. But when I tested them on firefox, most specs failed.

The first condition:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.DELETE).perform();
```

This action does not work on firefox.

The second condition:
when I want to right click an element, usually I use this:

```
browser.actions.click($(#id)).perform();
browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

This does not work well on firefox. It will not right click on the selected element, but somewhere else.But it has actually done the right-click action. I found a similar issue which has the same condition with me. [Protractor click svg element breaks on latest firefox(v.34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546598/protractor-click-svg-element-breaks-on-latest-firefoxv-34)

Would you please help to check these two issues? Thanks in advance.